# mpirun bind-to core What is bind to core? and How do I used this function?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing

I need to know more about the function bind-to core in mpi.

mpirun -np 4 --bind-to core

I launched 4 procesess but I dont know if I run this procesess one per core physical or one per core logical.

Comment: What is your MPI implementation (where did you get the mpirun), is it OpenMPI?

Comment: Yes! is OpenMPI.

Comment: Which one? What is exact version of OpenMPI, is it linux? Did you build it or just downloaded from openmpi site or from your linux distribution? What is your hardware card for interconnect network?

Comment: It is 2.1.1. I buid it, is for linux distribution and is an Infiniband network.

Answer (score 1):

*Core* refers to a *physical* one. The other *logical* thing is called *hardware thread*, e.g. `hwthread` for [OpenMP mpirun)](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man1/mpirun.1.php). In technical documents these are used unambiguously most of the time.